# Prevent Paramiko from Exiting

Tags: python, ssh, terminal, paramiko

## Description

I'm trying to write a python script to SSH into my VM and execute some commands.

- If I do it manually, my session stay open, and I can still see my **logs live**.
- If I use the script, after SSH in and automate a few commands, it kept exiting out and return to my user prompt. I'm trying to prevent that.

---

## Video

Manually =
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/ssh_wag_manually.mov

Via Python Script =
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/ssh_wag_py.mov

---

This is what I have right now

```
import paramiko
import time
import sys

# Note
# sudo pip install --user paramiko


def ssh_con (ip, un, pw):
    global client
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    print ("Connecting to device/VM: %s" % ip)
    client.connect(ip, username=un, password=pw)


def cmd_io (command):
    global client_cmd
    client_cmd.send("%s \n" %command)
    time.sleep(1)
    output = client_cmd.recv(10000).decode("utf-8")
    print (output)

# ip = raw_input("Enter WAG IP : ")
# ip  = sys.argv[1]

ip = '172.168.200.300'
un = 'xyz'
pw = 'abc'

ssh_con(ip,un,pw)
client_cmd = client.invoke_shell()

print ("SSH CONNECTION ESTABLISHED TO vMEG %s" % ip)
cmd_io ("en")
cmd_io ("terminal monitor")
cmd_io ("debug wag https")
cmd_io ("debug wag httpc")
cmd_io ("debug https")
cmd_io ("debug httpc")
cmd_io ("debug wag kafka")
```

---

Result

```
[local]site#
terminal monitor 
[local]site#
debug wag https 
[local]site#
debug wag httpc 
[local]site#
debug https 
[local]site#
debug httpc 
[local]site#
debug wag kafka 
[local]site#

.... Quitting and return the command prompt ....

──[/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/python] 
└──
```

---

How would one go about preventing this?

Comment: When does the SSH session exit: immediately, or after a certain amount of time, or after you enter a command,or something else?

Comment: Basically after finished the last line of the script ...

Comment: Well, your script is ending, so naturally any TCP connections opened by the process would be closed. Do you want the script to continue running? Do you want the ssh connection to somehow survive the script exiting? What do you want to do with this ssh session after all of the commands have finished executing?

Comment: I would like the script to continue running, let the SSH window with those commands stay opened, and not returning prompt, until I type `exit`

Comment: @Kenster : Naturally any TCP connections opened by the process would be closed, I didn't know that.

Comment: @JohnGordon : Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? You're running this script in a window, and you need the window to stay open so you can...read the output or something before the window closes? Is this your goal?

Comment: @Kenster : Yes, correct. If the windows close, I won't be able to see my debug logs, and that's my **main** goals is to see those logs.

Comment: why dont you just write what you want to see to a file?

Comment: If it is a one command and one time thing, I would definitely do that, but in our VM, we have a **terminal monitor mode** where we can just leave it, and all the logs will be live rendering, if any of my APIs call are failing so on and so forth, and that is the main reason for me to create this script, and asking this question.

Answer (score 4):

Your main issue is that you simply stop reading the output from paramiko.  If you want the program to continue to wait for further output from your VM, you need to tell it to do so.  For example this should do the trick:

```
import paramiko
import time
import sys
import socket

# Note
# sudo pip install --user paramiko


def ssh_con (ip, un, pw):
    global client
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    print ("Connecting to device/VM: %s" % ip)
    client.connect(ip, username=un, password=pw)


def cmd_io (command):
    global client_cmd
    client_cmd.send("%s \n" %command)
    time.sleep(1)
    output = client_cmd.recv(10000).decode("utf-8")
    print (output)

# ip = raw_input("Enter WAG IP : ")
# ip  = sys.argv[1]

ip = '172.168.200.300'
un = 'xyz'
pw = 'abc'

ssh_con(ip,un,pw)
client_cmd = client.invoke_shell()

print ("SSH CONNECTION ESTABLISHED TO vMEG %s" % ip)
cmd_io ("en")
cmd_io ("terminal monitor")
cmd_io ("debug wag https")
cmd_io ("debug wag httpc")
cmd_io ("debug https")
cmd_io ("debug httpc")
cmd_io ("debug wag kafka")

client_cmd.settimeout(1.0)
while True:
    try:
        output = client_cmd.recv(10000).decode("utf-8")
        print (output)
    except socket.timeout:
        pass
```

However, this doesn't solve *all* the problems.  Your script should also really be handling possible error conditions more rigorously.  For example, it should be reading the stderr stream, checking if the channel has actually been closed and doing something more than just wait 1 second for each command to complete.

This lack of error handling is all probably fine if it is just a quick script.  But if you need it to work 100% reliably, you will need to address them at some point.

Comment: First thank-you so much for your answer, explanation, and advice, it works great. Although, I have a few questions.

Comment: 1. `you may need to add extra sends to that loop if pressing enter`, what do you mean extra send ?

Comment: You are using an SSH client, so you `send` any command to the VM and `recv` any output from it.  It wasn't clear in your video if just using recvwould work, or whether you'd need to send  a new line periodically or not.  The exact meaning ofthat code is covered in http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.0/api/channel.html

Comment: To clarify, I don't need to sent any new line, after my last command ` debug wag kafka ` that is all I need. Thanks for getting back to me on this. I noticed I can't kill the window with `Ctrl+C` Or `Ctrl+D`  ... I want to check with you on that. Do I need to take care of that in my python script ? It will be great if you can combine the rest of my python code with your as part of your amazing answer. :D

Comment: OK - that's because I've oversimplified the code and it is blocking inside the recv command.  I've updated the answer with something that will allow you to press Ctrl-C to kill it.

Answer (score 1):

Put this function on the top of your script

```
def write_and_print_logs(log_message):
    with open("debugLogs.txt", 'a') as logs:
        logs.write("{}\n".format(log_message))
    print(log_message)
```

And now replace each `print(<message>)` command with `write_and_print_logs(<message>)`. Everything will now be written to a file, you can open it and see what happened no matter if you saw the logs in real-time.